# Почему создается пустая миграция в EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Установленные пакеты:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

```
public partial class HelloappContext : DbContext
{
    public HelloappContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data source = D:\\helloap.db");


    }
}
```

Есть модель User.cs.
Когда пишу команду Add-Migration InitialCreate создается пустая миграция. Ну и естественно после Update-Database создается пустая бд с одной таблицей __EFMigrationsHistory.
Почему так?

Answer (score 0):

Пустая миграция появляется только тогда, когда Entity Framework не обнаружил изменения в наблюдаемых файлах, т.е., в классах таблиц (энтитях или entity), конфигурациях таблиц, контексте базы данных и т.д.

Для проверки этого вы можете просто несколько раз подряд дать тестовую миграцию и посмотреть что будет внутри них